# Portrait photography

Tags: portrait, shutter-speed, iso, night

Is there any advice for shooting portrait in dark room, using only lamps. I am little bit confused with iso,aperture and shutter speed because i photographing with analog film.

Comment: In a dark room, with film, you will almost certainly need to use some sort of artificial lighting, e.g. flash. Can you add more info to your question with regard to any artificial lighting you intend to use? What camera are you planning to use? What film do you intend to use? What's your experience with flash exposure? What effect are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: If you want to avoid flash, then... have you metered the scene? What aperture/shutter speed/iso is suggested? Again, what film/camera/lens are you using? It's possible that the scene will simply be too dark without any additional artificial lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Lamps aren't that bright, but can be *bright enough* depending on your film choice and lens selection. For example, Delta3200 pushed to 6400 and shot at f/1.4 gives a reasonable shutter speed even with just a couple of 40W bulbs.

You need to get a meter reading in the scene and see what it says. If the scene is very dim and you can't increase the light, then you need to use the fastest aperture you can and potentially push some film. Portra 800 pushed up to 1600 is still pretty nice if you want to shoot color, and Delta3200 pushed for B&W.

If you want more help with a particular photo, take an image of the scene with your phone along with what the meter says to a new question. Also let us know what lens you'll be using along with the film that you'd prefer to use.